# iPhone SDK log to base 10

Tags: iphone, math, sdk, numbers, logging

Is there a method for determining the base 10 log of any number in the iPhone language? Any help with the math for this would be appreciated by a newbie budding iPhone developer.
Thanks in advance.
M

Answer (score 4):

Objective-C is an extension of C--you can use the C `log10` function from `math.h`:

```
#include <math.h>
@implementation MathUtils
+ (CGFloat)log10:(CGFloat)value
{
    return log10(value);
}
@end;
```

Answer (score 1):

logA(x) = ln(x)/ln(A)

Answer (score 0):

```
log_n x / log_n 10
```

where log_n is log to any base

Answer (score 0):

Why bother wrapping it in an ObjC method?  As you say, Objective-C is an extension of C:

```
#include <math.h>

float doSomeComputation(float x)
{
    // ...
    float y = log10f(x); // drop the 'f' if you're using doubles
    // ...
    return y;
}
```

Perfectly valid Objective-C.